# Is $f'(x)-3f(x) = 0$ subspace of differentiable functions $f\colon (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$V$ is space of differentiable functions $f(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $W$ is a subset of $f$ that meets $f'(x) - 3f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in (0,1).$

Is subset $W$ a subspace of $V$?

I know that I have to prove that it's closed under scalar multiplication and under addition. But I forgot all the stuff about differentiable functions, so I don't know how to do this. But my intuition tells me that if there's a zero it's valid subspace :) If anyone could elaborate on this I would be grateful.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ separately satisfy the differential equation, it is easy to show that $\alpha f + \beta g, \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$ satisfies the same differential equation. This works because the DE is linear, and the constraint is compatible. This formulation is used to cover both scalar multiplication and addition in one go, and is sometimes found in lecture notes and text books. You will find that doing the two separately involves tedious repetition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly. Let $f, g$ be two differentiable functions satisfying the given conditions (i.e., $f, g \in W$, and let $c$ be a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$. Then we can see:

$$(f+g)'(x) - 3(f+g)(x) = f'(x)+g'(x) - 3(f(x) + g(x)) = (f'(x) - 3f(x)) + (g'(x) - 3g(x)) = 0 + 0 = 0,$$ i.e., $(f+g)(x) \in W$, and

$$(cf)'(x) - 3(cf(x)) = cf'(x) - 3cf(x) = c(f'(x) - 3f(x)) = c(0) = 0,$$

i.e., $cf(x) \in W$. So $W$ is clearly closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Observing that $f(x) = 0$ is obviously in $W$, we are done.

Comment: You sir type fast :) Thanks. How could I forget these obvious rules.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help and glad you understand! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $f,g\in W$ so $f'(x)-3f(x)=0,~g'(x)-3g(x)=0,~~x\in (0,1)$. Now try to verify if $$[\alpha f(x)+g(x)]'-3[\alpha f(x)+g(x)]=0,~~~\alpha\in\mathbb R$$

Answer (score 1):

Taking the derivative is a linear map from the space of differentiable functions to the space of functions. This is just fancy speak for $(f+g)=f'+g'$ and $(cf)'=cf'$.
Multiplying with a constant is also linear, the sum of linear maps is linear.
So finally $f\mapsto f'-3f$ is a linear map from the space of differentiable functions $(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ to the space of functions $(0,1)\to\mathbb R$ and your $W$ is simply the *kernel* (maybe this is where your "if there's a zero, it's a valid subspace" intuition comes from) of this linear map, hence a subspace.